# Search nearby places for a specific radius within the core-data database [swift]

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, cllocation

I have a database in my core-data which consists of the following elements
**Place Name, Place Latitude, Place Longitude**. I am showing the user the place names using `UITableViewController`. In a seperate table i want to show the user with nearest places around him for a specific radius say 5000m. How can i show only those places whose coordinates lie within the 5km radius from the users current location.

So far i am able to get user's current location. I can calculate the distance from current location to a specific coordinate using the `CLLocationDistance`
Also i came across `CLCircularRegion` after spending some time on stackoverflow.
But couldn't really figure out the right way to solve my problem. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift

Comment: @AdrianB thanx for the link. It's not exactly what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

What flavour database server do you have?

You can accomplish what you need with spatial queries but their support is somewhat limited.

A spatial query on a spatial fields that have a good spatial index can return accurate results quickly and prevent the need for calculating the distance between every place and your user.

Comment: i have a local database. I have no idea about spatial queries.